# Firefox event target element is different from Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Hello I've got a question regarding defining the target that called my function. Let me explain myself by some code. I have the following HTML code:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Hoc non est positum in nostra actioneLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
<span class="link" onmouseover="Test()"><b>Test link</b></span>
Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Hoc non est positum in nostra actioneLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Hoc non est positum in nostra actioneLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Hoc non est positum in nostra actione
</p>
```

Within this paragraph there is `<span>` containing an event listener. I want to know which target (because in my production environment I have multiple objects that makes the call to my `Test` function) triggers the function call.

Therefore I use the following JavaScript code:

```
if (!document.addEventListener) {
  document.attachEvent('onmousemove', displayPos);
} else {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', displayPos, false);
}

function displayPos(e) {
    e_ff = e || window.event;       
}

function Test(){
    var target = "";
    if ( $.browser.mozilla == true) {           
        target = e_ff.target;           
    }
    else{           
        target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;
    }       
    console.log(target);
}
```

The output of the target in Chrome and IE is: `<b>Test link</b>`

The output of the target in Firefox is: `<p></p>` which is not desired.

Is there a way within Firefox, without knowing the siblings of the trigger, to get the exact same target as within Chrome and IE?

Perhaps important to note. I can not pass any attributes via `Test()` therefore I needed to create the `addEventListener` function.

Demo available here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ka82vtg6/)

Comment: Try to avoid using obtrusive event handlers. Oh, and `$.browser` is removed as of `1.9` (unless you use the Migrate plugin mentioned here > http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that! Thanks for noticing. @BenM

Comment: Sorry to inform you my friend it works exactly same for chrome and firefox. Verfied..

Comment: I think you missed something in your fiddle

Comment: What am I missing? @AkshayKhandelwal

Comment: not sure what you missed but your fiddle works exactly as you'd expect in case of chrome in the question

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery? The only thing in your code that's relative to jQuery is `$.browser`

Comment: @Rotan075 I think you should make sure you're following up-to-date javascript tutorial. What you're doing is something that was needed 6 years ago and is no longer valid. The main problem is that global `e_ff` is not same as `window.event`, which is actually not global.

Comment: "*I can not pass any attributes via Test()*" are you sure you can't, or just don't know how? Answer would differ based on that. But even if there are reasons to not pass the parameters, there are cleaner ways for workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple big problems with your code. Some of them stem of your incorrect effort for browser compatibility. I will list them in the order:

#### 1. Not defining global variable `e_ff` correctly (and using it in the first place)

For clarity, **if** you need to use global variables, declare them properly, ideally at the top of the document.

```
// Global refference on last mousemove event
var e_ff;
```

#### 2. Using `window.event` in Google Chrome, Opera etc

Your condition:

```
if ( $.browser.mozilla == true) {           
    // Firefox 
}
else{   
    // Chrome, IE, Opera       
    target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;
}
```

The **`window.event` is a [long deprecated IE only feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)**. By long deprecated I mean that even IE probably doesn't use it anymore.

Even **if it was valid**, it would still result in different behavior, because in IE the value of `window.event` depended on context. You would find different event ovject in your `e_ff` and `window.event` in IE.

#### 3. Not using event callback properly

If you really need to use `onXXXX` HTML attribute, please be aware that two variables are available in the callback value:

- `this` - refference to the element (`<a onclick="alert(this.title)" title="Hello :)">Try me</a>`)
- `event` - refference to event object (`<a onclick="alert(event.button)">Try me</a>`)

Therefore you should do this:

```
<span class="link" onmouseover="Test(this)"><b>Test link</b></span>

function Test(element) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

Even better:

```
<span class="link" onmouseover="Test.call(this, event)"><b>Test link</b></span>

function Test(event) {
    console.log("Element ", this, "hovered and caused event: ",event);
}
```

I hope you noticed I dropped the global mouse move listener entirely as it's useless.

---

*Solution without passing parameters (because OP **insists** on it):*

If for some reason you can't figure how to pass parameters, use a global variable, but do it properly. I would do this:

```
var lastHoverEvent = {element: null, event: null};
function registerLastHoverEvent(e) {
    lastHoverEvent.event = e;
    lastHoverEvent.element = this;
}
```

Then call it before the `Test` method:

```
<p onmouseover="registerLastHoverEvent.call(this,event); Test();">Hover me</p>
```

And in test use it:

```
function Test() {
    console.log(lastHoverEvent.element);
}
```

Javascript is single threaded so there will be no race condition in above. However the solution is ridiculous, indicating flawed logic in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I know that this the right way to do it. But I am building further on the fundamentals of someone else. The reason why I need this setup is because I have multiple inline calls to the function like `Test("content",Title, "This is a title", WIDTH, 500);`. If I have to add to each function call `this` then it would be a lot of work and not the ideal situation. Therefore I created this workaround

Comment: What is exactly the problem with using `this`? It's not a parameter, technically speaking. I'm talking about `Tast.call(this, "content",Title, "This is a title", WIDTH, 500)`. I will also add alternative dirty solution, but you should really rethink your design.

Comment: Because, for example, I have a situation on 1 website page where I have 30 Test() calls with each different arguments. Then for only this page I need to add 30 times the `this` argument. Which is not ideal.

Comment: And you have never heard of search and replace? It exists for exactly this purpose. I think I gave you a pretty good answer, the problem that remains is that you insist on writing bad code because you're lazy. That's not a programming problem and I can't really help you.

Answer (score -1):

It does look like a timing issue. You are calling two functions (handlers, additionally mixing onmouseover and javascript). In FF your mouse is probably out of the span/link/whatever before Test() kicks in.
So you probably want:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].addEventListener('mousemove', Test, false);
```

and

```
function Test(event){
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

Possibly even "mouseover".

Comment: No the problem is that `e_ff` in Firefox is global that gets changed in the `document` mouse move callback, while `window.event` is IE's pseudo-local variable for the event's execution chain. So he's using different event objects in different browsers.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I wrote, plus a solution.